Error when calling new operator - malloc.c:2379
I am trying to create a dbus proxy using a MyDBUS library I have been assigned
The problem is, when I try to do new MyDBUS() the program stops and a malloc error comes out on the screen output, before eternally waiting for who knows what input
This is the first time I encounter a new operator failing to do a malloc, but from what I read it could be from heap corruption? It is also puzzling how the same code works at least half a dozen times throughout the project but not here.
As far as I know the new operator creates a new instance of the object so it shouldn't be interferring with the other instances, even if inside the MyDBUS object I have several std::unique_ptr to various proxies and adaptors
MY CODE
int CreateDBusHandler( std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS > &dbusHandler )
{
    std::cout << "Initializing dbusHandler and interfaces..." << std::endl;

    try
    {
        // create local DbusHandler instance and connect it to event loops
        std::cout << "PRE CREATE" << std::endl;
        dbusHandler = MyDBUS::create();
        std::cout << "POST CREATE" << std::endl;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    { /* ... */ }

    std::cout << "End initializing dbusHandler and interfaces..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio( true );
    system("echo STARTING DBUS HANDLER");

    std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS > dbusHandler;
    CreateDBusHandler( dbusHandler );
    

    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

LIBRARY CODE (with added cout)
While on the MyDBUS library I have this static create function and the constructor it calls
static std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS > create()
{
    std::cout << "CREATE FUNCTION START" << std::endl;
    MyDBUS* tmpDbusHandlerPtr = new MyDBUS();
    std::cout << "CREATE FUNCTION STOP" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "CAST TO SHARED_PTR" << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS > tmpShared = std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS >(tmpDbusHandlerPtr);
    std::cout << "RETURN SHARED_PTR" << std::endl;

    return tmpShared;
}

MyDBUS::MyDBUS()
{
    std::cout << "PRE CREATE BUS CONNECTION" << std::endl;

    seshConnect = sdbus::createSessionBusConnection();
    sysConnect  = sdbus::createSystemBusConnection();

    std::cout << "POST CREATE BUS CONNECTION" << std::endl;
}

SCREEN OUTPUT
The compilation goes smoothly, but when I try to launch it I see the log
STARTING DBUS HANDLER
Initializing dbusHandler and interfaces...
PRE CREATE
CREATE FUNCTION START
malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

From the amount of logs shown, the program stops when it calls new MyDBUS(). The most peculiar thing is it doesn't crash but eternally remains there until I stop it.
Any idea?

First, don't do std::ios::sync_with_stdio( true );. That's just cargo cult programming. Then also don't do system("echo STARTING DBUS HANDLER");. What's wrong with using std::cout for that output? And your create function could be replaced by a single line: return std::make_shared<MyDBUS>();

As for the error, that is typical for when you have written to memory out of bounds somewhere else in your program. If your compiler have a sanitizer then use that to find out more (for Clang and GCC use the options -g -fsanitize=address,undefined).

Something is wrong in your exposed code: static std::shared_ptr< MyDBUS > create() (2nd snippet) is not the definition of MyDBUS::create() (called in 1st snippet). The former is a free-standing function, the latter a static member function of class MyDBUS.

My crystal ball tells me there could be something wrong with the library itself, but it’s hard to learn more without looking into its source code. Provide a minimal reproducible example, please.

And if the sanitizer can't help you, then please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. [Edit] your question to show it, together with any possible sanitizer output.

This is unfortunately the most I am allowed to share, as it's covered by copyright.
As for the things you noticed could be improved:

system("echo ...") was part of an earlier attempt to find what the hell was wrong
make_shared was my first idea but the constructor is private so I can't use it
the create function is defined in the class header for MyDBUS so that is indeed the definition of MyDBUS::create()

I'll try with the sanitizer, see what comes out of it

note: I tried many times to edit this to make it legible but with no avail...


Wait a second. If MyDBUS() constructor were private, you couldn't write new MyDBUS(); either. Anyway, if the main consisting of only new MyDBUS(); hangs as well then the problem is with the library. Check if there is some function like InitDBUS() which must be called before creating any objects, it's a relatively frequent library design quirk.

I can call new MyDBUS(); because create is part of the class and so it has access to the constructor. Also, the same exact sequence of commands works for other programs in the same build and it works there so I am left quite stumped

Again, please create a proper [mre] to show us.
